# Back on ViewPager my GoogleMap Fragment isn't visible

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, supportmapfragment, android-nested-fragment

I'm currently facing a problem with my *`ViewPager`*.  I've got a ViewPager with in the first tab a *`Listview`*, and in the second a FrameLayout to use the ***`Google Maps Fragment`*** (both called from a layout inflate via a different `Fragment` => *`ResultsListFragment`* and *`ResultsMapFragment`*).

When I change the fragment for my *`ViewPager`* fragment, it works for the first time, it load the data, etc... When I touch the back button, I return to my previous fragment (everything normal) but when I launch for a second time, the **`ResultsListFragment`** is create as it supposed, but not the ***`ResultsMapFragment`***. The ***`SupportMapFragment`*** is created and found with the method findFragmentById() but not visible.

Does anyone has this problem ? Or know how I could fix it ?

---

**Here the code into my ResultsMapFragment:**

```
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_map_results, null, false);
    if (mView != null) {

        SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment));
        if (mMapFragment == null) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.map_fragment, mMapFragment).commit();
        }

        if (mMapFragment != null) {
            mMap = mMapFragment.getPolarisMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onCreateView| " + "Found the google map by Polaris!!!");
                //// CODE TO ANIME VIEW, ETC...>>>

            } else
                Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView| " + "Ain't found the map by Polaris!!!");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was coming from the fact that I was using the ***`getSupportFragmentManager`*** instead of the ***`getChildFragmentManager`*** due to the nested design I'm using, I've just changed it in my ViewPager instantiation and it solved everything :)

Hope it would help anyone.